# How to select table names and then count the number of records in each

Tags: mysql

I have a lookup table called family_names. It contains an id and name. Each name corresponds to a unique table <s>called family_members</s> which has a record for each family member.

For example, family_names might consist of:

table family_names

```
1 Doe
2 Smith
```

And then we would have a table named Doe and Smith.

Table doe

```
1 Wife
2 Child
3 Child
```

Table smith

```
1 Husband
2 Child
```

I want to write a query that selects all the names from family_names. However, I also want it to return the number of family members for each family.

The query should return the following.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Doe",
    "count": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "Smith",
    "count": "2"
  }
]
```

I am having a difficult time approaching this query. What approach might you take? For example, correlated subquery, joins, etc.

Comment: I apologize. My original question was misleading. I hope I have made it more clear.

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding this.  Does your system actually create a mysql table for each value in family_names?  This is horrendously bad practice.

Comment: @user870130 If you have the freedom to build it,  I suggest a two table structure as follows:  family_names(ID, name) and family_members(ID, family_ID, relation_type).  The family_ID column would join to the ID column in the family_names table.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Select family_names.name, count(*)
from family_names join family_members on family_names.name = family_members.name
group by family_names.name
```

(Note: I haven't tested this but I believe I have the syntax correct)

Comment: this is correct, but doesn't work with the poster's original (and very bad) table structures.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, the table structure was added in an edit after I posted my answer. It is, to your point a poor table design. I'll note that to the poster if it hasn't been noted already.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you ca use a group by on inner join

```
select family_names.name , count(*)
inner join family_members on family_names.id  = family_members. name_id
group by family_names;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query.

example :

```
Select name,
(select count(*) from family_members where family_members.id = family_names.id) as count
FROM family_names;
```